# How to include csv files into when building image in Docker

Tags: c#, docker

How to include CSV files into when building an image in docker?

I tried to do

```
COPY Test.txt.
WORKDIR /app
```

Where should I put my Test.txt file? It seems like it cannot find it at all... 
I want it to be copied to /app.

Comment: Add your Dockerfile code

Comment: you put Test.txt on the same path where Dockerfile is present  and in dockerfile write COPY Test.txt /app/Test.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right order to include a file is

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY Test.txt .
```

With that you have /app/Test.txt in the resulting container

You can also use ADD instead of COPY

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: You almost always want COPY, unless you explicitly want Docker to fetch a remote URL or unpack a tar file.

Comment: @wolmi is there a way I can browse in the files in the image and open to see the content?

Comment: @DavidMaze It seems like the file has been added but when I run the code I'm getting error that it cannot find file:

            foreach (var test in Directory.GetFiles(@"/app/"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(1 + test.ToString());
            }

            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"/app/Test.Txt");
            Console.WriteLine(text);

Comment: You can use `doker run` to execute custom command on a container, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: @wolmi In this case I want to create a new folder in working dir /App that is called config and add those files to that folder. How can I do this?

Comment: Add to the dockerfile a RUN step and execute one command to create de folder just between the WORKDIR and the COPY lines and modify the COPY to put the file inside the new folder

Answer (score 0):

I not exactly understand what the dot after the Test.txt should mean.
You just have to define your working directory (I assume you already did) and copy the file there:

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY Test.txt /app/
```

Comment: The dot is because at the moment you put the WORKDIR line the context of the build is inside that folder,then you can COPY on the current for with the dot